# Impala Data types

Tags: sql, impala

I'm trying to understand the difference between the following data tyoes in Impala

1. String
2. Char
3. Varchar

Being schema on read what would be the need for 3 different types. I am wondering if there's any performance benefits of using Char/Varchars over Strings in scenarios where we know the upper bounds on column lengths?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`STRING` stores variable length data and is (essentially--barring some practical limitations, of course) unbounded.

`VARCHAR(x)` stores variable length data with an upper bound of x characters, so data will be truncated to the defined length. For example, if you have `VARCHAR(10)`, your input data can have size in [0,10].

`CHAR(x)` is an x-character fixed-size data type. Data is padded if it is shorter than x. Data is truncated if it is longer than x.

Both `VARCHAR` and `CHAR` were introduced in Impala 2.0.0 (CDH 5.2.0) and are mostly useful for compatibility with other database systems. However, both `VARCHAR` and `CHAR` are not recommended except for some special use cases (with specific legacy systems) as both have some functional limitations.

While there should be similar performance between `STRING` and `VARCHAR`, `CHAR` has some different characteristics: notably it is not codegen'ed so typically performance will suffer. However, small `CHAR`s (where `x < 128`) are stored along with the tuples during execution rather than in auxiliary memory as variable length data is.

The above provides some differences between these types, but it is recommended to use `STRING` whenever possible.

See the [STRING](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/latest/topics/impala_string.html), [VARCHAR](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/latest/topics/impala_varchar.html), and [CHAR](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/latest/topics/impala_char.html) docs for more details.

Comment: Matt thanks for the response. If I understand this right it makes more sense to use String vs VARCHAR(x) **even if** we know the upper bounds to make it easy for Schema Evolution. Are these types defined in Impala for compatibility reasons or any specific cases where 1 makes sense over other. I would really love to see a document which explains when to use each data type and why.

Comment: Yes, STRING should be easier to use for schema evolution reasons. VARCHAR is mostly useful for compatibility with code from other or legacy database systems that use VARCHAR types.